# 400 - Bad Request while saving Date Only field in CRM using Web API

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi, microsoft-dynamics-webapi

I am using **Microsoft Dynamics 365** ***Web API*** approach to interacting with CRM data.

Here I want to update the field with type: `DATE and TIME`.

[image: Screenshot of field setting]

Date value I am passing in the request body is as below:

```
"packfirstday":"1-15-2018"
```

Except for above, I have also tried with DateTime and with different date formats.
e.g.

```
mm-dd-yyyy
m-dd-yyyy
mm/dd/yyyy
yyyy/mm/dd
yyyy-mm-dd
```

**PS**: I try to post without date field it is saving details successfully.

Comment: Can you include sample POST request & response ?

Comment: Be careful with your dateformat too. Isn't `mm` minutes? If you want months I think you need `MM`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the code, the simple misunderstanding.

There are 2 components namely Behavior & Format. You have Format set as 'Date only' not the [Behavior](http://dynamicscrmcoe.com/behaviors-date-time-fields-few-concerns/). Behavior decides the Database terms whereas Format is used for displaying datepicker controls in Form.

[image]

So when you set the field in web api with only date part - the CRM database expects time part also.

Either set behavior also as date only, so this will work:

```
"packfirstday":"2018-01-15" //YYYY-mm-dd format
```

Or change your code to pass time part also:

```
"packfirstday":"2018-01-15T11:10:00.000Z" //UTC offset
```

Since user local behavior still expects the time part.

Comment: I tried 1st approach **setting behaviour as Date Only** creating another field and it is **working as expected**. 

**_But as I do have a client's CRM and once I change the behaviour to `Date-Only` it won't allow again to change that field._**

So I tried with 2nd approach i.e. using **UTC offset** on the existing field but it is not working and throwing error **400-BadRequest**. 

Can you guide me through this second approach?

Comment: As edited, it was expecting '.' instead of ':' for the milliseconds. Marked as the answer for your help @Arun sir. Thank you again.